# Does using statement close all kinds of streams in it?

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, using-statement

I have `using` statement to close the `OleDbConnection` and then I'm working with the reader.
I'm wondering if I have to close the reader at the end or I can rely on the `using` statement to close it.

I've got the following code:

```
string connectionString = @"Some connection"; 
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) 
{ 
    string query = "SELECT ID, Name, \[Position\] FROM Players"; 
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection); 
    connection.Open(); 
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 

    while (reader.Read()) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine($"ID.{reader\[0\]} {reader\[1\],-18}{reader\[2\]}"); 
    } 
    reader.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: You need to call Dispose(by using the using pattern) yourself. For the reader AND the command.

Comment: Closing the datareader is automatic when the connection closes. So it is not required to add a _using_ just to close the reader. BUT. The rule is clear. If a class implements the IDisposable interface you should dispose.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb:

Use the `using`-statement for everything that implements `IDisposable`.

So yes, use the `using` also for the `OleDbDataReader` and the `OleDbCommand`.

But you can simplify all to this:

```
using var connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Some connection");
using var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, Name, Position FROM Players", connection);
connection.Open();
using OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID.{reader[0]} {reader[1],-18}{reader[2]}");
}
```

Comment: Tim Schmelter, which language version of C# are you using? Because this construction "using var connection" is not working?

Comment: @zaraboy is already available since VS 2019, just use C#8